# AS3 NPC conversation dialogue structure

Tags: actionscript-3

I have coded a simple tile based RPG engine so far, where you can interact with objects (for example and NPC) by pressing 'x' next to them. At this point I am able to display a box at the bottom of the screen, with some text (defined at will). I need to be able to organize conversation structures such as this:

[image]

At this point it does not bother me exactly how the conversation is defined (whether loaded from an XML file, or using factory methods); I should have no trouble doing that in the future. All I need is some guidelines regarding how I should lay out my class structure.

So far, I can't think of any ideas; my brain is paralyzed with inability to find a solution. I probably need some sort of conversation class, with arrays of text that the NPC has to say. But then how do I know who's talking, or what line they have to say based on the plot events. This kind of problem seems a bit over my head.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840154/rpg-dialogue-engine-structure), as well. I guess what I need to know is how to actually use that data.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the question is too broad. And it's so, because of the fact that there are many ways to solve it, and second - because everything depends on your current code structure as well as your skills..

But here's a little idea - you should use what's called states (and/or state machine). Because you have different interactions (like first talking, then entering something, then talking with someone else), you will need a class that will hold the current progress of the player. There you can have list of actions that must be done. Changing the state means having different index on the current action (which is actually a progress).

The action class itself can have a type (if it is a talk or another player action), as well as target (person to talk to; place to visit).

Of course this is the very basic fundamental on which I think you should build upon. As I said - there are numerous ways to achieve that, but for sure you will need to provide a list with actions from different type, and keep their progress. Having such class will also help you to serialize (save) that progress. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this maybe didn't completely answer the question, but it at least set me in the right direction. I have a working prototype now :D