# Web RPG - Storing dialog

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'd like to create an RPG in JavaScript. The RPG will have a lot of dialog in it. I have heard [XML is the way to go...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372915/game-logic-in-xml-files), but I have no experience using XML, and a good amount of experience with PHP and MySQL.

My questions are:

- Would it be better to store dialog in a MySQL database and access it with PHP using IDs? Or should I just keep it all on the front end by accessing XML files with Javascript?
- If I use XML, do I need to run the javascript on a webserver (Like WAMP)? Or can I parse it locally with:

  ```
  function parseXML() {
      xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET","dialog.xml",false);
      xmlhttp.send();
      xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;             
  }
  ```

(Which is currently giving the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users... Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

- Even after reading up on XML, I'm still not sure how I can integrate it with JavaScript. Can someone help give me an example of how I could take a sample rpg XML dialog and meaningfully parse it in JavaScript?

Thank you

Comment: You may look to JSON and document-oriented databases. It would be convenient to store JS object and accessing them without conversion to XML.

Comment: I would echo @SerjZaharchenko comments. JSON is much more compact, and easier to work with in javascript.  Also if you are going to have a whole series of dialogs that are going to be in a tree structure and you need to retrieve the whole tree with a single ID, then NoSQL database might be a really good option.

Comment: No, the Cross-origin error is due to him using the file:// protocol, and the browser disallows such requests. I guess he's just opened the HTML page with his web browser, but he's not vising a location actually served by any HTTP server. AFAIK, Firefox would allow him to perform "AJAX" requests on the file:// protocol too.

Comment: @Esailija Thank you for the brief explanation; I deleted my comment to prevent misunderstanding from other people.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use JSON instead? It's much easier to use from JavaScript code. While you're at it, avoid usind XMLHttpRequest by hand and use some library that handles the bad stuff for you (e.g., jQuery).

For the "dialog" part, I'm not sure what you're gonna use MySQL for. Anyway, you can use any form of storage on the server side, provided that your PHP scripts give well-formed replies to the client side code.

Comment: I was going to use the MySQL to store references to the dialog text by ID, which could be accessed based on game logic by PHP then brought forward by JQuery. Anyway, can you give an example of how I could use JSON to store dialog that can be accessed based on logic defined in Javascript? For example... I have a set of conditional scripts to respond with if an NPC asks me to do something. And, what file type do I store the external JSON as?

Comment: Think about separating your *transport* format from your *storage* format. JSON is great for transport, but not necessarily storage, and XML isn't really great at anything. You'll need a way of converting your data stored in the database into JSON for rendering purposes, but this is how most applications work.

Comment: Well, JSON is simply a serialization format like XML, but with a different notation which is largely borrowed from JavaScript (as the name itself suggests, as JSON means "JavaScript Object Notation").

You could organize the structure like a tree, where each node represents an object containing a field `question`, which would be the `String` object containing the actual question, and a field `answers`, which would be a dictionary linking answers to other "question objects", and so on.

Mind that this will only work if your question data doesn't have loops (or it won't be serializable).

Comment: @tadman then what format is a good way to store the actual dialog text? And how could I store it in such a way that it can be associated to IDs? My confusion here is that I thought JSon would be the storage and transport format as you could have JSon files on the webserver where its data is stored in Tags to be referenced later by ID

Comment: Unless you love smashing around and editing XML or JSON by hand, which is error-prone at best, you'll probably want to create some kind of front-end where you can edit the dialog and save it into MySQL as a series of related records. Then you'd have a method of retrieving these records, associating them internally, and emitting the JSON you require. This way, you can edit and test immediately. Once your dialog is finalized, I'd actually go so far as to pre-render all the JSON out into static files for performance reasons, but the content would be identical to that produced dynamically.

Comment: @tadman mind providing a resource or writing out a simple example that includes JavaScript, JSON, PHP and MySQL and focus on how I'd use JSON to get data I need?

Comment: If you're going to use PHP for this, you should start by using a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) to handle interfacing with the database to get you the data you need to convert to JSON. Writing [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) applications is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @tadman so the actual text will be stored in a database? Or will the database just reference a text file stored on the file system? Also, what about other items? Are they loaded to the canvas via Javascript or from the database via PHP -> JS?

Comment: It's usually much easier to keep structured data in a database as fields in records, then emit that in an arbitrary format as required by your application. The usual method is database -> PHP -> JavaScript  when executing. I'm more familiar with [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) where this sort of thing would be about fifty lines of code and could be banged together in an afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be better to store dialog in a MySQL database and access it
>   with PHP using IDs? Or should I just keep it all on the front end by
>   accessing XML files with Javascript?

The main advantage of having a database here is that you gain a lot of flexibility. You can create/edit/delete a piece of dialogue and its relations quite easily and without having to maintain/regenerate a huge data file every time (As you would do with a XML or JSON or w/e formalism you choose).

On the other hand, this solution might be overkill if you just have simple dialogues with no relations and limited content.

Since you are about to do a game in Javascript, and if your content is not changing that much, you can consider a JSON encoding for your dialogues. You could parse the data instantly via Javascript and still have the possibility to make all kind of complex relations between dialogues as you would in XML.

> If I use XML, do I need to run the javascript on a webserver (Like WAMP)? Or can I parse it locally with: ...

You have this error because you indeed need to run a server here. If you just want to do some tests, no need to use WAMP or whatever big webserver, just run a python server for now and that will do the trick.

```
cd /yourProject
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Let the server run and open your browser at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the input file a base url like `http://localhost/rpgame/dialog.xml`.