# I cant decide the best way to store strings for what I'm trying to achieve

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been given the task to make a text based game and I am opting to go with a dating sim. I have all the dialogue written out but I am stuck on where I would store the dialogue. At first I thought of just making a lot of if statement ex( if you pick this option it takes you to this) but this seems to be really inefficient. So I dont know whether it would be better to have them in an array or array list and just go to that specific place in that array. Sorry if that was confusing that was some background I guess im asking what is the best way to store strings in a game revolving around conversations.

Comment: Learn OOP. You won't need million if statements.

Comment: Text like this is usually stored in data files (in the Java world, `.properties` and XML are probably the most widely used ones). To navigate the dialogue, you could use a finite state machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague but of course, other people before has been working on it.

A good starting point (with lot of references) could be, "Gameplay Design Patterns for Game Dialogues" Jenny Brusk and Staffan Björk

On the other hand, [Dialog Trees](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/how-do-dialog-trees-work) (and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/how-do-dialog-trees-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372915/game-logic-in-xml-files)) is a way to store dialogs but can work or not for your specific needs.